# Como adicionar um campo no no format.bibtex e exibi-lo, utilizando a classe IEEEannot.bst

Tags: latex, bibtex

Estou usando a classe do [IEEEannot.bst](https://www.barik.net/sw/ieee/) para fazer levantamentos bibliograficos e queria inlcluir um campo no arquivo bibtex, como atributo de @article, e depois exibir esse campo nas referências do PDF. Sou muito beginer no LaTex syntax e não sei exatamente o que preciso alterar para fazer isso. Já fiz uma alteração de uma função que deu certo, mas esta não estou conseguindo.

Esta foi uma alteração que fiz que deu certo, o objetivo é colocar o texto anotado em negrito:

## Alteração que deu certo: Antes

```
FUNCTION {format.annotate}
{ annote empty$
    { "" }
    {  " "
        annote
        * "" *
    }
    if$
}
```

## Alteração que deu certo: Depois

```
FUNCTION {format.annotate}
{ annote empty$
    { "" }
    { 
        " \textbf{ "
        annote
        * "}" *
    }
    if$
}
```

A função `format.annotate` é chamada mais adiante no código, em uma seção como a seguinte:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ 
  % Code here...
  format.annotate write$
  % Code here...
}
```

## Alteração que quero agora

Pra fazer o que eu quero, criei uma nova função e chamei ela como no codigo acima:

```
FUNCTION {format.link}
{ doi empty$
    { "" }
    {
        ""
        doi
        * "" *
    }
}
```

Na chamada não tenho certeza de como fazer, mas fiz algo assim:
    FUNCTION {article}
    { 
      % Code here...
      format.annotate write$
      format.link doi
      % Code here...
    }

Mas nada foi alterado. 
Obs.: `annote` é uma propriedade de `@article`, no arquivo bibtex, assim como `doi`.
Mesmo quando eu chamo a propriedade `doi` dentro de um método que funcione nada acontece. Não conheço muito bem a sintaxe do LaTex, então alguém saberia onde está o erro? como eu poderia pegar uma propriedade do bibtex e mostrar no documento?